# Помогите написать программу на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите реализовать программу обработки имен пользователей (`деНиС` - преобразовать к `Денис`)
Или подскажите, как мне реализовать данную программу.

Comment: `print('деНиС'.title())`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот пример как из строки `'деНиС'`

```
'деНиС'.title() # Денис
```

Answer (score 3):

Другой вариант:

```py
'деНиС'.capitalize() # Денис
```